# Integer division using only addition, multiplication, subtraction and maximum

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, logic, lambda-calculus

Suppose we have a programming language ℤ which has the following syntax:

```
ℤ := 0 | 1 | (+ ℤ ℤ) | (* ℤ ℤ) | (- ℤ ℤ) | (max ℤ ℤ)
```

For convenience, we can define new binding forms in our language as follows:

1. `(not x) = (- 1 x)`
2. `(abs x) = (- (max 0 (+ x x)) x)`
3. `(min x y) = (- 0 (max (- 0 x) (- 0 y)))`
4. `(nil x) = (not (min 1 (abs x)))`

This language is powerful enough to express branching and comparison operators:

5. `(if x y z) = (+ (* x y) (* (not x) z))`
6. `(eq x y) = (nil (- x y))`
7. `(ne x y) = (not (eq x y))`
8. `(le x y) = (nil (max 0 (- x y)))`
9. `(gt x y) = (not (le x y))`
10. `(ge x y) = (le y x)`
11. `(lt x y) = (not (ge x y))`

Now, the question is whether we can define integer division is this language:

12. `(div x y) = ?`
13. `(rem x y) = (- x (* y (div x y)))`

I don't think that it's possible to define `(div x y)` because ℤ doesn't have loops. However, I don't know how to prove it. Note that if it's possible then the result of `(div x 0)` doesn't matter. Hence, either define `(div x y)` or prove that it's impossible to do so.

Comment: Does ℤ allow recursion?

Comment: No, it doesn't allow recursion. The binding forms are just a convenience. Recursive binding forms aren't allowed.

Comment: I see.  I assumed recursion because the syntax uses recursion, and you've assumed `max` as a pre-defined binding.  Please edit your question to differentiate between binding forms and legal language strings.

Comment: @Prune The BNF syntax is recursive. However, it doesn't encode binding forms yet alone recursive binding forms in the language.

Comment: It's clearly impossible, but I can't see a proof. I guess you'd be better trying at cs.stackexchange.

Comment: Simpler question: can you define `(odd x)` in this language? If not, then there's no hope for `(div x y)`.  (I would have asked about `(even x)`, but it looks as though there's an implicit requirement that all function names are three letters long ...)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yeah, I kind of went overboard with the three letter names. Edited.

Comment: I believe you should be able to prove (e.g., by structural induction) that any function `f` of a single variable `x` that's expressible in this language is *eventually* a polynomial: that is, there's some integer `x0` and polynomial `p` such that `f(x)` equals `p(x)` for all `x` exceeding `x0`. That should then prove that `(odd x)` is impossible (and hence that `(rem x y)` and `(div x y)` are impossible to construct).

Comment: I agree that it's impossible.  We proved it in passing in my college symbolic logic class.  I believe we did it by making a four-valued logic system and proving that division is independent of the other operations.

Comment: It may well be impossible for the particular language you have enunciated here, but if you constructed this language to try to formalize the question "can I implement / with just +, -, *, and comparison?" then the answer to that question is yes. To find a/b, just subtract b from a until you get a number less than b, counting the number of subtractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible.

Call a function `f : Z -> Z` *eventually polynomial* if there exists a polynomial `p` with integer coefficients and a threshold `t` such that, for every `x > t`, we have `f(x) = p(x)`. Let `d(x) = [x/2]` be floor division by two. `d` is not eventually polynomial, because the difference sequence of `d` has infinitely many zeros (`f(2y) = y = f(2y+1)` for all `y`), whereas the difference sequence of every non constant polynomial has finitely many. It suffices to show that all implementable functions are eventually polynomial.

The proof proceeds by structural induction. `0` and `1` are polynomial. It's straightforward to show that sums, products, and differences of eventually polynomial functions are eventually polynomial: use the max of the two thresholds and the fact that the set of polynomials is closed under these operations. All that remains is closure under `max`.

Let `f` be eventually polynomial via a polynomial `p`, and `g` be eventually polynomial via a polynomial `q`. If `p = q`, then clearly `x |-> max(f(x), g(x))` is eventually polynomial via the same polynomial. Otherwise, observe that `p - q` has finitely many real roots. Setting the threshold to an upper bound on the roots, we observe that the max function is eventually polynomial via `p` or `q` since the other case of the max never triggers here.

Comment: Well done; shorter and more accessible than the symbolic logic proof I've been trying to reconstruct.

Comment: Thanks for fleshing out my hasty cryptic answer-as-a-comment!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of recursion and branching will give you loops.

```
(div x y) = (iff gte(x y) (+ 1 (div((- x y) y))) 0)
```

In more functional terms, we're doing repeated subtraction.  If x >= y, add one to the quotient, subtract y from x, and recur.  Otherwise, return 0.

```
if x >=y
    return 1 + div(x-y y)
else
    return 0
```

Comment: Yes, but this language doesn't support recursion. Note that you're using `div` within the definition of `div`. That's not allowed. Binding forms aren't a part of the language, yet alone recursive binding forms. They're just a convenience feature to avoid writing long expressions.

Comment: I see.  I assumed recursion because the syntax uses recursion.  Please edit your question to differentiate between binding forms and legal language strings.

Comment: I did. The BNF describes the legal language strings. Before I introduced the binding forms I did mention that they are only for convenience.

Comment: Note that even if ℤ did support recursion, your function would still be wrong. It never terminates if the divisor is a negative integer and is smaller than the dividend, and otherwise it incorrectly returns 0 when the dividend is a negative integer.